# Show that the following statement is a theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers

Suppose h is not a counting number and h is greater than 1, then there is a counting number n such that h is between n and n + 1.

I am working through "Creative Mathematics" by H.S. Wall. The book gives you the axioms for an ordered field and additionally treats the definition of counting number as an axiom and treats least upper bound property as an axiom. I assume the point of this exercise is to use only these axioms along with some simple theorems you prove along the way (for example: -1*(-x) = x or x < x + 1). I don't have any reference to check my work and I feel like I'm not applying logic properly when showing that statements are theorems.

My approach to this particular task was to negate the conclusion and from there try to stumble into a counter example.

My negation of "there is a counting number n such that h is between n and n + 1" is "there is not a counting number n such that h is between n and n + 1" which, I am assuming, is equivalent to "for all counting numbers n, if h is greater than n, then h is greater than (or equal to) n + 1".

My next step was to suppose h is 3/2 and n is 1 and since 3/2 is greater than 1 and 3/2 is not greater than 2, then the statement that there is a counting number n such that h is between n and n + 1 must be true.

I don't feel confident that I applied logic correctly. I don't feel comfortable that I used a specific example (1 < 3/2 < 2) to prove that an n always exists so that for all non-counting numbers h greater than 1, n < h < n + 1; however, I have yet to come up with a different way to approach this problem.

Comment: What is this book's definition of 'counting numbers?"

Comment: The book gives this definition for counting numbers: The number 1 is a counting number. If x is a number such that x < 1, then x is not a counting number. If x is a counting number, then x + 1 is a counting number and if z is a number such that x < z and z < x + 1, then z is not a counting number.

Comment: What is your book's definition of "number" ?

Comment: Number isn't defined. I am assuming number means real number. I have yet to use a non-real number or prove any theorems requiring the use of non-real numbers in the exercises in this book.

Comment: Even with the edits, you still can't prove the theorem unless you add the assumption that $h$ is a real number.  For example, $h=\infty$ would be a counter example to the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right when you state:

"I don't feel comfortable that I used a specific example ($1 < 3/2 < 2$) to prove that an $n$ always exists so that for all non-counting numbers $h$ greater than $1$, $n < h < n + 1;$"

The existence of an example (or any number of examples for that matter) only shows that the hypothesis is true in (one or more) particular case(s), but it does not prove it holds in ALL cases. On the other hand, if you find just ONE COUNTER-example that contradicts the hypothesis, then you have proved that the hypothesis is not always true, and therefor it is false.

Now for the proof of the hypothesis:

*Suppose $h$ is not a counting number and $h$ is greater than $1$, then there is a counting number $n$ such that $h$ is between $n$ and $n + 1.$*

First let's show that any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is a counting number (by induction):

For $n=1$ we have $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ is a counting number (by definition).
*Induction Hypothesis*: Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\ge 1,$ and assume that $k$ is a counting number. Then its successor $\left(k+1\right)\in \mathbb{N}$ is a counting number (by definition, since $k$ is a counting number).
Then (by induction) all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ are counting numbers.

Next, let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the *largest* positive integer such that $n\le h.$ There exists such $n$ since $h>1$ is given. Since $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we know from the proof above that $n$ is a counting number, while $h$ is *not* a counting number, so $n\neq h,$ thus $n<h.$
Next consider $\left(n+1\right)\in \mathbb{N}$, so $n+1$ is also a counting number. Since $n$ was picked as the *largest* counting number such that $n<h,$ and $n+1>n,$ it follows that $n+1\not < h,$ so $n+1\ge h.$ Also, $h\neq n+1,$ since $n+1$ is a counting number while $h$ is *not* a counting number, so $n+1>h.$ Then we have
$n<h<n+1,$
so there exists a counting number $n$ such that $n<h<n+1,$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

$<$ could be a partial order, and even though all positive natural numbers are counting numbers, nowhere is it provable that all counting numbers are positive natural numbers.  Without substantially improving the assumptions, especially:

- The definition of $<$ here
- The definition of "number"

The statement is unprovable.  It's negation is also unprovable.

Suppose I create a new object, call it $X$, with the following properties:

> - $X$ is a "number"
> - $X$ is larger than any number except for itself
> - $X$ is a counting number

This would not contradict the definition of counting number, but would contradict your statement.

So depending on whether you choose

> - $X$ exists

to be true, false, or unassumed; the statement may be undecidable, disprovable, or undecidable.